# My Application doing too much work in main thread for loading images from SD in android

Tags: android, image, load

My application is about loading the images from a specific folder in the phone and then display it as GridView.

So far everything is ok but when I run the application it takes too much from the RAM and work and have some lag to scroll down to see the other images in the GridView

I want to make it smooth and not taking too much from the RAM so I don't get lag when I scroll down
this is the output in my log and as you see it takes too much bytes and work

```
09-16 12:57:17.458  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 37.655MB for 16343056-byte allocation
09-16 12:57:17.708  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 37.661MB for 16343056-byte allocation
09-16 12:57:17.868  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 53.252MB for 16343056-byte allocation
09-16 12:57:17.979  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-16 12:57:18.029  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 68.853MB for 16343056-byte allocation
09-16 12:57:18.249  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 84.440MB for 16343056-byte allocation
09-16 12:57:19.020  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 84.448MB for 16343056-byte allocation
09-16 12:57:19.240  14067-14067/com.b3du.test2 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 84.447MB for 16343056-byte allocation
```

My Code:

main.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        imageAdapter.getFromSdcard();
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

adapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
    File[] listFile;


    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return f.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        return convertView;
    }


    public void getFromSdcard()
    {
        File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/InstaDownloader-");

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            listFile = file.listFiles();


            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;


}
```

Comment: you need to run your task in an AsycTask

Comment: but isn't AsycTask for Data the from the internet I believe ? .. even thought I don't know what to put in the AsycTask , I only do have the Adapter to load the images and my main .. should I put all my Adapter in the AsycTask ? hmm

Comment: is there any complicated code before u set data in adapter?

Comment: @mtetno I have posted my full code .. this two classes are my classes to load the images so far .. but as I said it takes so much time and lag to upload it when I run the App ( see it ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this .. make a class inside imageAdapter and extend Async Task..

```
private class SetImage extends
            AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... thumb) {
            // Do something with bitmap

            return //Bitmap; //Returns this to onPostExicute
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // Set Bitmap to ImageView
        }

    }
```

and in your adapter class where you want to put image call

```
new SetImage().execute(//bitmap);
```

***And i would suggest not to pass bitmaps to Async task. insted pass the refrence to the image you want to set as a String. Then in do in background class, process the image and in post execute set the image to view.*** Async task makes a thread so that the main UI thread does not get a lot of work to do. if UI thread is working too much the frames drop and app might even crash on somedevices.. hope it helps..